# best way to store the configuration values in WP7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

Since there is no default configuration file In a WP7 app, what is the best way to store the configuration values, e.g. DB connection strings, API Urls. I want these values to be available easily and also updated easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are simple you could store them in the [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class.

If they get more complex, you could store them in a file (again in IsolatedStorage) with default values from within the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://sterling.codeplex.com/, which kind of database. I use it in my Todoist Lite. Works great for quering, saving, loading, etc. sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.  I this is what you're after?
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/198869-wp7-using-isolatedstoragesettings/